# copy files from different locations and with different names into one target directory

Tags: shell

i really looke for solutions for this , but all solutions just assume that either the file names are similar (like file1,file2, file 3...) so a regular expression can be used, or a FIND can look for the files with a certain name. But in my case i have different file names:
assume i have

file1 in E:\dir1\, input99 in C:\dir2 , result3 in F:\dir3

so these three files reside in different locations, different drive names, but still local

is it possible to use cp with absolute pathnames ?
like:

cp /dir1/file1, /dir2/input99, /dir3/result3 /targetdirectory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cp` accepts a list of source files (specified either as absolute paths or relative paths) and copies all of them to the target directory (the last parameter). So:

```
cp E:\dir1\file1 C:\dir2\input99 F:\dir3\result3 C:\targetdirectory
```